# Converting PDF to TIFF

Tags: pdf, tiff, file-conversion, pdf-conversion

I am looking for some tool or library (.NET version will be perfect) I could use to convert  some big PDF files (over 200MB) to TIFF in the product we are developing for our client. 
I need tool I could call from the command line or a library that I could use in the .Net application.

I have tested ghostscript, and it works perfect but according to its license, we cannot use it.

Do you have any experience with free or commercial products we could use for it? Could you recommend something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Ghostscript in commercial use, only thing you need is commercial license. Take a look here: http://www.artifex.com/page/licensing-information.html . If you decide to go with Ghostscript you can also take a look at the .NET Ghostscript wrapper: http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com

Comment: Yes, I know. I am waiting for the reply from Artifex (exclusive licensing agent) and testing another solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, they require too much information about our project to prepare formal licensing proposal

Comment: You could try with ABCpdf: http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you explicitly ask for commercial software as well, callas pdfToolbox performs this task. I'm affiliated with this company / product so draw your own conclusions about quality / price. However, the software:

- works perfectly on the command-line
- exports to PNG, JPG or TIFF (or rasterized PDF)
- exports to either grey, RGB or CMYK
- supports smoothing and overprint preview (important when you're in graphic arts, likely less so if not)
- is available on Mac OS X, Windows, Linux and Unix

Send me a private message if you want to know more.

Comment: Could you provide me with some link? I have found several products called pdfToolbox from different companies

Is it [callas Software pdfToolbox?](http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en:products:pdftoolbox)

Comment: You're correct, you can download a trial version here: http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en:download

Answer (score 0):

Gnostice PDFOne .NET has a PDFDocument.SaveAsMultiPageTiff() method that you can use.
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=215&t=Convert_A_Multi-Page_TIFF_To_PDF_Using_PDFOne_NET